# How to pass data from Phonegap view to architect view from wikitude

Tags: android, cordova, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am making a augmented reality / voice recognition app using Phonegap, wikitude and voicerecognizer (phonegap plugin). Almost everything works: The app launches the native speech api, saves the result in an input field, and then starts de wikitude ARchitect view. I have to put the value from the input field trough to the ARchitect view (this had to infect the models that show).

The Problem is: I've no idea how to do this.

I tried a lot of things but nothing worked. I was realy close to the solution trough a cookie, but when I tried to open the cookie in the ARchitect view it gave a security error.

**The question in short: How to pass data/variable between the Phonegap view and the Wikitude ARchitect view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikitude SDK for android has the following method:

> void callJavascript(String javaScriptCommand)
>   Executes the passed JavaScript string in the context of the currently loaded ARchitect World. This can be used to pass data to the ARchitect World or to notify it of external events.

Maybe there is something similar for the phonegap plugin.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a parameter that is NOT a String, to aMethod in `callJavascript("aMethod()")` ?